# mysqlnd_qc storage handler choice

Tags: php, query-cache, mysqlnd

I am trying to install mysqlnd_qc on our production server (I don't know if a good decision but I went for it)

I managed to get it installed and run. So far so good. My only concern is :

Is it ok to use the default storage handler. I know they support APC and memcache. But APC is dead, and memcache handler is [not working](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65549)